# Extract text under div class using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, python-3.6, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract text from this element:

```
<div class="_pac" data-bt="{&quot;ct&quot;:&quot;sub_headers&quot;}"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/%EB%B6%81%EC%9D%BC%EC%97%AC%EC%9E%90%EA%B3%A0%EB%93%B1%ED%95%99%EA%B5%90/110634532291267">북일여자고등학교</a><div class="_1my"></div></div>
```

I am trying to extract the text after href -

```
'북일여자고등학교'
```

So far I tried:

```
content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div._pac')

for i in content:
 i.get_attribute('text')
```

However, it is not returning anything. How can I extract the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are multiple `div` with the class `_pac` on you page. In your case it is locating first element and that has no text.

`find_element` methods locates the verify first element in case multiple occurrence is there of same element.

Try to make you locator more unique and specific to locate the single element. Refer below code :

```
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@data-bt,'sub_headers')]/a")
content.text
```

It seems you are looping the content but you have used `find_element` instead of `find_elements` so replace it with `find_elements` method

loop through all the text present in same kind of element use below code:

```
content = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div._pac')
for element in content:
   print(element.text)
```

Comment: This is what I did! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The desired text **북일여자고등학교** is within a child `<a>` node within the parent `<div>` node.

To print the text *북일여자고등학교* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `.get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div._pac>a[href^='https://www.facebook.com/pages']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_pac']/a[starts-with(@href, 'https://www.facebook.com/pages')]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output of two back to back execution:

  ```
  북일여자고등학교
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 0):

To extract text from `<a>` tag like you mean, use this css selector `div._pac > a`. Please try this solution:

```
content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div._pac > a')
print(content.text)

#or use '.get_attribute'
print(content.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

If there are multiple elements with same classification on the page, you can use **`.find_elements_*`**, it will return a list of webelemet, and extract them with loop:

```
content = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div._pac > a')
for el in content:
    print(el.text)

    #or use '.get_attribute'
    print(el.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to do that extraction BEFORE closing driver!
I had that issue because I had loop after driver.close() even when my variable element was filled with data!

**So loop BEFORE .close()**. 
Example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
...
LOOP for(..)...
...loop does smth...
driver.close()
```